# pure javascript detect change in number typed input value

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

```js
window.onload = function init() {
  console.log("DOM is ready!");
  var input, value;
  
  input = document.getElementById("yourGuess");
  input = input.value;
  
  input.addEventListener("checking", check, false);
  
  check(value);
  
}

function check(value) {
  if(input < 0 && input > 10) {
    alert("The number must be between 0 - 10");
    value = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="yourGuess">You choose: </label>
<input id="yourGuess" type="number" min="0" max="10">
```

I can't find any solution anywhere that correspond to the issue above.

So I have a number type input and declared a min and max attribute with the value 0 and 10 respectively.

The user can click the input field and change its value outside of range, hence I *need* to use javasricpt to check any changes made

Comment: Why are you doing this: `input = input.value;` Due to this, next line will throw error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You're overwritting your `HTMLInputElement` with the value which is string, hence you're getting error.
- Use `onchange` event along with `document.addEventListener`.
- I've `DOMContentLoaded` method which gives you better idea instead of using `window.onload`!

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
    document.querySelector("#yourGuess").onchange=check;
},false);

function check(event) {
   if(event.target.value > 10 || event.target.value < 0){
      alert("The number must be between 0 - 10");
      event.target.value = 0;
   } 
}
```

```html
<label for="yourGuess">You choose: </label>
<input id="yourGuess" type="number" min="0" max="10">
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues in your code

- You are setting `input` to the `input.value` so input becomes a `String` which doesn't have `addEventListener`
- Use `change` event instead of `checking`.
- `check` method doesn't have visibility to `input`, so rely on `event.target`.
- Your if condition needs an **OR** `||` instead of `&&`

**Demo**

```js
window.onload = function init() {
  console.log("DOM is ready!");      
  var input = document.getElementById("yourGuess");
  input.addEventListener("change", check, false);
}

function check ( event ) 
{
  var input = Number(event.target.value);
  console.log(input);
  if(input < 0 || input > 10) {
    alert("The number must be between 0 - 10");
    value = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="yourGuess">You choose: </label>
<input id="yourGuess" type="number" min="0" max="10">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function change(){
var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
if(num > 10 || num < 0){
alert("Number is not in range");
}
}
```

```html
<input id="num" type="number" min="0" max="10" onchange="change()">
```

if you type number manually then you should left that input field to check or you can use other methods such as onkeypress etc.

Answer (score 0):

- You are setting addeventlistener to the input value.
- You are trying to use input in check function but it is not available in that method as it is not defined in the scope of that function.

  ```js
      window.onload = function init() {
         console.log("DOM is ready!");
         var value;
         var input = document.getElementById("yourGuess");
         value = input.value;
         input.addEventListener("change",check)
      }
      
      function check() {
          if(this.value < 0 || this.value > 10) {
              alert("The number must be between 0 - 10");
                  value = 0;
              }
          }
  ```

  ```html
          <label for="yourGuess">You choose: </label>
          <input id="yourGuess" type="number" min="0" max="10">
  ```