# How to take average of only valid values in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to take an average of input values coming from 5 different text fields. But; sometimes, these fields have NaN or 0 values. In that case, I want the javascript function to ignore those values and only take the average of the values that are not null, or NaN or <=0.

Also, I want the javascript function to listen to all the events not just Keyup. Basically, how can I combine change, keyup and blur events into one function?

Here is the function that I have wrote so far.

```js
$(function() {

  $("#field1, #field2, #field3, #field4, #field5").keyup(function() {
    $("#avg").val(((+$("#field1").val() + +$("#field2").val() + +$("#field3").val() + +$("#field4").val() + +$("#field5").val()) / 5).toFixed(2));

  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <div>
      <label>Field 1</label>
      <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>Field 2</label>
      <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>Field 3</label>
      <input type="text" name="field3" id="field3" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>Field 4</label>
      <input type="text" name="field4" id="field4" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>Field 5</label>
      <input type="text" name="field5" id="field5" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>Average</label>
      <input type="text" name="avg" id="avg" />
    </div>

  </form>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Example:

```
Field1 = 10
Field2 = 20
Field3 = NaN
Field4 = 0
Field5 = 30
```

Desired Output:

```
Avg = 20
```

Comment: why would you want all those events? keyup is so granular it will cover the rest - though for form fields I would use `input`instead

Comment: @Kinglish sometimes, the field 1 to field 5 get values directly from another function without manual user input. So; in that scenario, I think the change function will only work. What do you suggest?

Comment: I had a solution but it won't work for programmatic changes to an input field per your comment. You can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47028665/pure-javascript-detect-change-in-number-typed-input-value

Comment: Divide and conquer. Make something that gets valid values and make something else that averages the values.  Maybe putting the entire program on one line was not the way to go.  Put the fields' in an array, use an Array.filter, write an average function that operates on an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the fields, testing whether they're valid before you add them to the total.

```js
$(function() {

  $("#field1, #field2, #field3, #field4, #field5").on("paste input change", function() {
    let total = 0;
    let count = 0;
    $("#field1, #field2, #field3, #field4, #field5").each(function() {
      let value = parseFloat(this.value);
      if (!isNaN(value)) {
        total += value;
        count++;
      }
    });
    $("#avg").val(count == 0 ? '' : (total / count).toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <div>
      <label>Field 1</label>
      <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>Field 2</label>
      <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>Field 3</label>
      <input type="text" name="field3" id="field3" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>Field 4</label>
      <input type="text" name="field4" id="field4" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>Field 5</label>
      <input type="text" name="field5" id="field5" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>Average</label>
      <input type="text" name="avg" id="avg" />
    </div>

  </form>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works. But, what did you mean by: "paste input change"?

Comment: Those are the 3 events that occur when you paste into an input field, make any change by typing, and when you leave a field after editing it.